# Positive eigenvalues and/or positive definiteness of $A^+DA$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

I have stumbled across the following fact in robotics.

Let $A$ an $m\times n$ matrix with $rank(A)=n$. Consider also a diagonal matrix $D$ with positive entries. The following two claims are posed:

1. Is $A^+DA$ is positive definite where $A^+$ is the pseudoinverse matrix of $A$?
2. Are the eigenvalues of $A^+DA$ positive? This is obvious if for example $A$ is a square matrix.

**Edit:** I just found an example showing that **claim 1. is not true** in general. Specifically, for $$A=\left[\matrix{1 & 1\\0 & 1}\right]\qquad,\qquad D=\left[\matrix{10 & 0\\0 & 0.1}\right]$$
then 
$$A^+DA+(A^+DA)^T=\left[\matrix{20 & 9.9\\9.9 & 0.2}\right]$$
which is not positive definite.

Comment: $A^+DA$ is not symmetric in general. What do you mean by positive definite in this case?

Comment: @user1551 Thank you for your comment. Indeed the matrix is not symmetric. I mean that for the corresponding quadratic form it holds true that $x^T(A^+DA)x>0$ for $x\neq 0$ which is equivalent to $A^+DA+(A^+DA)^T>0$

Comment: if A is an orthogonal then yes its symmetric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to (1) is no. Here is a counterexample:
$$
\begin{align*}
&A=\pmatrix{2&1\\ 1&1},\\
&B=A^{-1}\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&2}A=\pmatrix{0&-1\\ 2&3},\\
&B+B^T=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&6}.
\end{align*}
$$

The answer to (2) is yes. Since $A$ has full column rank, $A$ has a singular value decomposition $U\pmatrix{S\\ 0}V^T$ where $S$ is a positive diagonal matrix. Hence $A^+DA=VS^{-1}MSV^T$, where $M$ is the leading principal $n\times n$ submatrix of $U^TDU$. As $U^TDU$ is positive definite, so is $M$ by Sylvester criterion. Hence $A^+DA$ has a positive spectrum because it is similar to $M$.